# Android Studio - No LogCat from my App, only one error

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-studio-bumblebee

Something strange happened today - I opened my project, which by the way before it worked correctly, i.e. it showed logs in logcat but now it's not working.

I connect the phone to my laptop and Android Studio sees it, then I click "Debug", the application compiles, installs on the device and opens. Unfortunately in LogCat I keep getting this `PocketModeLiteSensor :input data file descriptor not available - (Bad file descriptor)` error. And this error is spamming my entire window - nothing more showing.

Also, my Android Studio start to showing a message, that i run out of memory (on my laptop) - this never happen before!

I have the latest Android Studio and i make fresh install of it like two weeks ago.

Comment: Did you try quitting Android Studio and restarting it? What about restarting your computer?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
I restarted Android Studio several times and it was the same every time.
After restarting the computer and opening the project, LogCat showed all logs (from debug, info, error, etc.) but as soon as I click "Debug" and the application installs on my device and opens, only the above-mentioned error appears - nothing more . Debug, Info etc. are empty.

I would like to add that I did not change anything in my code - I just started Android Studio, clicked "Debug" and from that moment only this error appears